# Language Engines VS. Runtimes VS. Process Virtual Machines

Tags: compilation, runtime, interpreter, vm-implementation, javascript-engine

Since the rising popularity of JavaScript, I found it intriguing to hear (even during the [same speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlmsweSNhTw)) either about JavaScript *engine*, or about JavaScript *virtual machine*, or JavaScript *interpreter*, in the same context and referring to the same thing.

Therefore I've tried to do some research, why all those buzzwords do coexisting simultaneously (there *must* be a reason) and if there are some real (although slight) differences between them.

I'm trying to summarize what I've learnt so far, from many different sources (which I've quoted in the following lines). Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong/misleading with something.

Although I've found out that the runtime-duties of all of them are basically the sames, I've found also some main differences:

1. Process virtual machines

   - are the [most complex](https://www.quora.com/Is-V8-the-JavaScript-engine-a-virtual-machine-platform-like-the-JVM-If-not-in-what-way-is-it-different) (implements even the IO, [virtual instruction set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441824/java-virtual-machine-vs-python-interpreter-parlance) [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678060/interpreters-vs-compilers-vs-virtual-machines))
   - always includes an [interpreter + intermediate language](http://www.slideshare.net/nwind/virtual-machine-and-javascript-engine/6-How_Virtual_Machine_Work_Parser)
   - [besides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253303/how-does-the-java-runtime-environment-compare-with-the-net-framework-in-terms-o) may include also compilation (*just-in-time* and/or *dynamic recompilation*)
   - applications run only inside VM process as a thread
   - coupled to an runtime environment
   - examples: Java Virtual Machine, Dalvik Virtual Machine
2. Runtimes

   - does not abstract away from native code
   - uses *solely* [compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564348/is-the-clr-a-virtual-machine) techniques (either [*just-in-time* or  *ahead-of-time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_application_virtualization_software))
   - lacks a VM process/sandboxed applications
   - tight-coupled/dependencies to the underlying operating system
   - examples: Common Language Runtime, Android Runtime
3. Language Engines

   - more lightweight
   - may use either an [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) or [compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine)) ([*just-in-time* and/or *dynamic recompilation*](http://www.slideshare.net/nwind/virtual-machine-and-javascript-engine/88-Unlocking_the_JavaScript_Opportunity_with))
   - decoupled from underlying environment/operating system
   - exemples: all JavaScript engines, Zend Engine

**Questions:**

- is the upper list accurate, or is it just a byproduct based on totally coincidental similarities between most common runtime systems, which use the same denomination?
- are there also other noteworthy differences?

Comment: As a mostly higher-level programmer I've always wondered the differences too. I think due to the similarities and emerging nature of evolving technologies people tend to speak loosely and will use some of these terms interchangeably. I hear this a lot with "compiler" and "transpiler". Thanks for the summary, I found it helpful!

Comment: I don't think your conclusion is correct. And you didn't provide references for every line. This kind of conclusion without references is dangerous, and usually misleading. I would recommend that you either delete it or delete it anyway.

Comment: @Rainning please provide arguments why and what exactly you think it is not correct. Since this is a question, not an answer, those are no final conclusions, but the result of the research I’ve done prior asking (research which is mandatory according to the rules of SO, when asking) for which I’ve asked for feedback. All lines are based and covered by provided links (just did not repeated the references).

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

The virtual machine is a concept that represents how one could decouple the actual instructions that your CPU will use to execute your program and your human-readable source code. You, the programmer, are able to write less code that does more.

### Longer answer

I'm pretty sure that you're looking for an answer that's much simpler than the classifications that you outlined in your question. Typically, a virtual machine simply stands for the abstraction that is inserted between the source code that you've written and how the physical hardware receives those instructions.

All of those nitty-gritty details that are needed to talk to the processor are handled by a "virtual machine", which itself automates many of the repetitive commands that might be required to do a very simple operation, like manipulating a string UTF-8 encoded characters and printing them to the command line. Python uses one, Java uses one, and the class of "Language Engine" that you outlined above is just a fancier name for the same concept of a virtual machine. Any VM can be as fast and lightweight as the VM programmer designs it to be, which will play into both the usability and reliability of the applications are developed for it.

As is the case when using Java and Python, you're able to write programs using verbose languages that have very little in common with the "language" that the physical processor needs in order to execute commands. Thankfully, people that are far smarter than I am have created programs using that processor-specific language, called the "assembler" or "assembly" languages, which differ between instruction set architectures (e.g. RISC-V, x8/x86-64, ARMv8). These programs are what can translate what you've written into that processor-specific language procedurally, essentially acting as a translation layer.

What you could potentially end up with is a far simpler interface between you, the developer, and the hardware that you're trying to leverage. To boot, the only thing that you need in order to run the program across different OS environments is for the VM to have been implemented in whatever assembly language is used by the physical host processor.

*Note: I say* can *because of the **very** subjective nature that is the appreciation of any given language's syntax.*

To give a high-level example, the Python "interpreter" that we can use both to execute pre-written scripts and interact with in a command-line application relies on a compiler that creates the Python bytecode from your code, which is then fed into the so-called Python Virtual Machine for processor execution.

Also, there's no real difference between a *virtual machine* and a *"language engine"*. The JavaScript language engines, such as Google's V8, are simply implementations of this virtual machine concept that allows for developers to rely on platform agnosticism and portability when developing dynamic, web-based applications without worrying about breaking the usability of their programs.

If you're interested, look into the various implementations of Python (Jython, IronPython, etc.). These use the conceptual virtual machines implemented by other languages/frameworks, like Java and .NET, to create an implementation of Python that uses the same syntax, but gets cross-compiled into Java bytecode or Common Intermediate Language bytecode instructions to achieve the same results. The "python interpreter" that is almost universally referred to is the C-implemented interpreter that is officially maintained by the Python Software Foundation, colloquially named "CPython".

Just to really drive it home, here's a prime-checking algorithm written in Python, C++ using C libraries, and x86 ASM (x86 assembly language) by xmdi on youtube, and you'll be able to see how the Python VM enables the kind of syntax that allows people to easily get into programming without losing their mind trying to juggle register manipulation using assembly language:

### Python:

```py
def isPrime(n):
    for i in range(2,n//2+1):
        if (not (n%i)):
            return 0
        return 1

numPrimes = 0

for i in range(2,250001):
    numPrimes+=isPrime(i)

print(str(numPrimes))
```

### C++:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(int n){
    for (int i = 2; i <= n/2; i++){
        if (!(n%2)){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(){
    int numPrimes = 0;
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= 250001; i++){
        numPrimes += isPrime(i);
    }

    printf("%d\n", numPrimes);

    return 0;
}
```

### x86 ASM:

```
.section .data
    f: .string "%d/n"
.section .text
    .globl main
    main:
        movl $2, %eax
        xor %r8d,%r8d
    loop:
        cmpl $250000,%eax
        jg end_loop
        movl $2, %r10d
        movl %eax,%r11d
        shr $1,%r11d
    prime_loop:
        cmpl %r11d,%r10d
        jg prime
        push %rax
        xor %edx,%edx
        div %r10d
        test %edx,%edx
        pop %rax
        je not_prime
        inc %r10d
        jmp prime_loop
    prime:
        inc%r8d
    not_prime:
        inc %eax
        jmp loop

    end_loop:
        lea f(%rip),%rdi
        mov %r8d,%esi
        xor %eax,%eax
        call printf
```